# sending array via query string in guzzle

Tags: php, rest, query-string, restful-url, guzzle

[Guzzle](http://guzzlephp.org/) client creates by default from this code

```
$client->get('https://example.com/{?a}', array('a' => array('c','d')));
```

this url

```
https://example.com/?a=c,d
```

What is the best practice to send array in query string in RESTful application? The question is, how can I determine on the server side whether `c,d` is a string or an array? Isn't it better to send arrays using square brackets, e.g. `a[]=c&a[]=d`? How can I set Guzzle to use square brackets? Or it is better to use JSON encoded variables? On the server side I'm using [Tonic](http://peej.github.com/tonic/).

Comment: I'm interested in the same

Answer (score 5):

Working Solution:

```
$vars = array('state[]' => array('Assigned','New'), 'per_page' => $perPage, 'page' => $pageNumber);
$query = http_build_query($vars, null, '&');
$string = preg_replace('/%5B(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]+)%5D=/', '=', $query); // state[]=Assigned&state[]=New
$client = new Client([follow instruction to initialize your client ....]);
$response = $client->request('GET', $uri, ['query' => $string]);
```

Now you have same name parameters in your request.

Dung.

Source: [http_build_query with same name parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170306/http-build-query-with-same-name-parameters)

Answer (score 5):

Guzzle has a helper function you can use called `build_query()`. This uses PHP's `http_build_query()`.

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
$params = [
    'a[]' => [
        'c',
        'd'
    ],
    'page' => 1
];

$query = \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\build_query($params);

$response = $client->request('GET', 'https://example.com/', [
    'query' => $query
]);
```

Comment: `build_query` is now deprecated and the suggested alternative is `\GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Query::build` which does exactly the same thing

Answer (score 4):

It seems the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12283180/1218080).

I wanted to do something like `?status[]=first&status[]=second`

You can do this in Guzzle like shown in the link above:

```
$client = new Client('http://test.com/api');    
$request = $client->get('/resource');    
$query = $request->getQuery();    
$query->set('status', array('first', 'second'));
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure this quite answers the question. But I found the question while looking for how to construct complex queries using Guzzle and none of the answers here were the solution I ended up using. I'm adding it here in case it's ever useful for any other devs.

Using Guzzle 6, you can do this type of request:

```php
    $endPoint = "https://example.com";

    $queryParams = [
        'a' => [
            [
                "b" => "c"
            ]
        ]
    ];

    $options = [
        'debug' => true, // so you can see what the request looks like
        'query' => $queryParams
    ];

    $client->request('GET', $endPoint, $options);
```

As a real world example, query params like this:

```php
    $queryParams = [
        'filters' => [
            [
                "field" => "status",
                "value" => "open",
                "operator" => "equal"
            ],
            [
                "field" => "total",
                "operator" => "greater_than",
                "value" => 50
            ],
        ],
        'limit' => 500,
        'start' => 7
    ];
```

produce a url like this:

`https://example.com?filters=[{"field":"status","operator":"equal","value":"open"},{"field":"total","operator":"less_than","value":50}]&limit=500&start=7`

The point being that the `query` key of the `$options` array, seems very powerful. I'd recommend having a play with that before going down the route of writing complex regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = array('x' => array(
                    'a',
                    'b',
                    'c'
        ));

$query_string = http_build_query($query, null, '&'); //build query string

$query_string = preg_replace('/%5B(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]+)%5D=/', '[]=', $query_string); //x[]=a&x[]=b

$response = $guzzle->client->get($path, array('query' => $query_string)); //Make guzzle request

return json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents()); //Return JSON decoded array
```

This is how you can process `x` with array of values in guzzle, tested with version 6 or later